Flapping wing bird gazebo simulation
This was done for my semester 5 individual project of my university department, I chose this ornithopter designing as my project because simulation process seems interesting. after some struggle I came to know that I can use gazebo with custom plugins to fake the physics so that I can do a simulation of a flapping wing bird. So, I carried out some works in my plugins and the plugins works fine. But how can I improve this further.
Edit:
I couldn't do soft body dynamics in gazebo. I have given up the project. But I need to know what I could have done better. what are the other tools that could have used for soft body dynamics
This is my Git hub repository link

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Congrats on the development! However, the Robotics StackExchange is a 'questions' board. For announcements like yours, it is better to post them on the ROS Discourse.

Thanks for the advice, and sorry for my poor English didn't call attention to the question
